# Error when viewing profiles

Tags: bug

When I click on my user on the top bar, and then navigate to the Profile tab, I get the following error screen.

https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/24087/dr-r-dizzle

This also happens whenever I try to go to another users profile. As far as I can see, private profiles are not suffering from this issue.

What's happening?

Update: The error seems to have been fixed.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Weird.

Comment: @CandiedMango Hmmm, I think it is working for me now too.